# Nested If Else Update Query in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a table with two columns `Days` and `Status`.

I have to populate `Status` based on another lookup table.

```
Min -- 4
Max -- 6
Range -- 5 and 10
```

At a point of time there can be min / max / range populated.

Based on that Range, `Days` must be filtered and `Status` is updated to either `success` or `failure`.

Example:

```
MAX - 6
```

Means `Status` is set to `success` for those records for which `Days` have a maximum value of 6.

Comment: Range is a text field with string "5 and 10"? How should this be used to calculate desired result? Edit question to show sample raw data and desired result - as text tables, not images. What have you already attempted?

Comment: You'll have to [provide](http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) sample data and expected result for us to be able to help you. 
[How to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271).